# nginx ssl client certificates with signed root and intermediate

Tags: authentication, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I am trying to set up ssl client authentication. I am using startssl as a CA if that makes any difference. I obtained a root certificate, an intermediate certificate, and a client certificate from startssl. I also have several s/mime certificates for authentication against the startssl website. What I am trying to accomplish is to have client certificate authentication for my own site. Everything works using self signed certificates, but using the signed certs I get confused.

I have the following files from startssl:

```
root.crt
intermediate.crt
ssl.crt
ssl.key
----------------
user@host-client.crt <- for authenticating against startssl
```

Then for nginx I run:

```
cat ssl.crt intermediate.crt root.crt > unified.crt
```

Then in nginx:

```
server {
    listen        443;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/ssl.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/<WHAT GOES HERE>;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        root           /var/www/example.com/html;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to use as for `ssl_client_certificate` if I want to use the startssl s/mime cert, or if that is even possible.

If I can't use the startssl s/mime cert: in a tutorial like [this](https://gist.github.com/952344) what would I use as ca.key and ca.crt (possibly the unified ssl?).

In either case, how do I determine the `ssl_verify_depth`? I have found many examples of how to do this with self signed keys, but as far as using a signed key chain, my understanding starts to lag. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you have figured it out already, but I had the same issue and this howto from startssl helped me setup everything correctly: http://www.startssl.com/?app=42   I'm not going to answer your question by copying and pasting the article.